# Proof of Equation by Well Ordering Principle

Tags: real-analysis, summation, induction

I have an assignment question

> Prove by either the Well Ordering Principle or induction that for all nonnegative integers $n$: $$\sum_{k=0}^n k^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

I am able to solve this question using basic Induction, but not able to figure out how to do it by using Well Ordering Principle.

Any Solutions or hints would be very helpful.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that the statement is not true.

Then the set $A=\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}\mid\sum_{i=0}^{n}i^{3}\neq\left(\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}\right)^{2}\right\} $
is not empty.

Since $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered set $A$ has a minimal
element $m$.

That means that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}i^{3}=\left(\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}\right)^{2}$
is true for $n<m$ and is not true for $n=m$.

From this you can deduce
a contradiction.

(Start with $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}i^{3}=\left(\frac{\left(m-1\right)m}{2}\right)^{2}$
and prove on base of that $\sum_{i=0}^{m}i^{3}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}i^{3}+m^{3}=\left(\frac{m\left(m+1\right)}{2}\right)^{2}$)

The conclusion is then that $A=\emptyset$ wich is
exactly the statement to be proven.

Comment: Why the equation is true for n < m? Why it couldn't be n>m? @drhap

Comment: @QuangHuy If $n<m$ then $n\notin A$ because $m$ is minimal element of $A$. That means exactly that the equation is true for $n<m$. Further I am not saying anywhere that the equation is not true for $n>m$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there are counterexamples. Take a minimal counterexample $n_0$...

Comment: I am not able to arrive at a contradiction to prove that no such set of counterexamples exist.

Comment: The formula will be true for $n=n_0-1$?

Answer (score -2):

For $n=1$ the left side is equal to $1$ and the right side is also equal to $1$ so the equality holds true.
Suppose that the equality $(1)$ holds true for some $n\geq1$ then for $n+1$ we obtain $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^3  =\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^3 +(n+1)^3 = \frac{n^2 (n+1)^2 }{4} +(n+1)^3 =(n+1)^2\left(\frac{1}{4} n^2 +n+1\right) =(n+1)^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} n +1\right)^2 =\left(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right)^2 .\fbox{}$$

Comment: You don't answers OP, he says that he can do that but not the proof using the well ordering principle...